# Ext GWT : Add clicklistener to the children of a Tree

Tags: gxt

I adapted this [Tree Sample in GXT](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/BasicTreePanelExampleExtGWT.htm) to my web app, so I would like to know how (and where)  can I add an OnClickEvent Listener or something similar, that when I click in a child node (I only have one tier) this open a new tab

So I know how to add the new tab but I would like to know how to add the ClickEvent child element per child element.

Here is a capture of my app.
[image]

Reply me if you don´t undestand something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add selection change listener on a tree (TreePanel) like this..

```
  tree.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener<ModelData>() {

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent<ModelData> se) {
              ModelData m = se.getSelectedItem();

              if(isChildElement(m)) {
                   //Open the new tab here...
              }
        }
}
```